# Query language for Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

So I'm learning .NET Core with EF and have gone through a few tutorials. What I haven't seen so far is a good walk through of what query-language is used. I've seen two approaches be used so far:

- The function oriented approach:

examples are:

```
_context.Exams.ToListAsync()
_context.Problems.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ExamID == exam.ID
students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString) || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
```

and sometimes these are strung together:

```
_context.Students
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

- The SQL-looking approach:

I think only one example is needed:
`from problem in _context.Problems where problem.ExamID == examID select problem;`

So my question is, what are these two called respectively? When should you choose one over the other (I believe I saw one tutorial using both). And are either one of these examples of LINQ-queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from s in _context.Students where s.ID == 1 select s;
```

I believe this one is referred as the query syntax type LINQ expression.

and this one

```
_context.Students.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == 1);
```

some people call this format as ***method based linq query expression***. This one is more explicit (for some people)

These are just names and it is a personal preference for people to pick which one they want to use. The important thing to understand is, both formats will produce identical result.

Also i think when the code is executed , The C# compiler does convert the first form into it's equivalent method based expression as part of internal [lowering process](https://ericlippert.com/2014/04/28/lowering-in-language-design-part-one/).